# The best textbook on Fourier Transformation for beginners

Tags: fourier-analysis, book-recommendation, fourier-transform, fast-fourier-transform

I am absolutely new to Fourier Transformations. I have a bit of background in Trigonometry. Which text book would you recommend to learn Fourier transforms from the very basics?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You should have used the `book-recommendation` tag (I did it for you).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest T. W. Körner's *Fourier Analysis*.

Comment: While an excellent book, I don't think this is a book for "beginners"...

Answer (score 1):

Ronald N. Bracewell's *The Fourier Transform & Its Applications* is an excellent, thorough book on the subject.  The pictorial "dictionary" of transform pairs in the back of the book is a handy reference.

However, I don't know how good the book is for beginners with only a trigonometry and algebra background.  Any decent study of Fourier transforms is at least going to require calculus.